# Can we use non-power-of-2 textures on OpenGL ES on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Does anyone know if it is possible to use NPOT textures on Android's OpenGL ES renderer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, for OpenGL ES 2.0, NPOT textures are supported in the core specification with some limitations in wrap modes, and 3D textures. The limitations are lifted when using the GL_OES_texture_npot extension.

For OpenGL ES 1.x, there is no extension to support NPOT textures.

Comment: And to support only ES 2.0 and higher you can use `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Froyo does has a NPOT implementation for OpenglES 1.1. However, so far I can not get UI to displace with proper aspectio. I think Froyo has issue with this implemenation, based on a quick review of the code. Gingerbread has updated a better design like Apple's method, but I can get Gingerbread to work yet. I am having very hard time making Android to work for HW ES 1.1 that needed NPOT work-around. Has any one out there got NPOT to work with HW Opengl 1.1 with Froyo/Gingerbread ?

Jimmcwin